# Why is the colour picker displaying tinted colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface, color

The colour picker is behaving not as I expect it to. I cannot move the selector towards most of the edges, setting the RGB to 1.00 for red and the rest to 0 just gets an orange colour. Also I cannot simply keep the "value" the same and select a different shade, the "value" resets.

I'm not sure if i've pressed something in error or there is a setting in the user preferences/elsewhere that needs changing.
I'm using the cycles renderer. The issue occurs with any colour picking :- material, background etc. Quitting Blender and restarting does not resolve the issue. Version 2.79.6

[image: colour picker]

[Colour picker behavioiur easier to see](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/PartialNimbleCob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scene tab set Display device to sRGB.

[image]